# How to simplify a switch statement to reduce the cyclomatic complexity

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement, refactoring

I have a big switch statement that has a cyclomatic complexity of 31 and it must be refactorized to at least 25. 
This is the error: Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   CA1502  'Worker.StartListening()' has a cyclomatic complexity of 31. Rewrite or refactor the method to reduce complexity to 25.

Thank you!

Here is the code:

```
public void StartListening()
    {
        var consumerSettingsSection= this.configurationManager.GetSection<ConsumerSettingsSection>("appZ/consumer");
        foreach (var setting in consumerSettingsSection.QueueSettings)
        {
            var eventType = ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified;

            switch (setting.Name)
            {
                case "A":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.A;
                    break;

                case "B":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.B;
                    break;

                case "C":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.C;
                    break;

                case "D":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.D;
                    break;

                case "E":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.E;
                    break;

                case "F":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.F;
                    break;

                case "G":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.G;
                    break;

                case "H":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.H;
                    break;

                case "I":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.I;
                    break;

                case "J":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.J;
                    break;

                case "K":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.K;
                    break;

                case "L":
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.L;
                    break;

                default:
                    eventType = ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified;
                    break;
            }

            var consumer = new ChannelConsumer(setting, eventType);
            consumer.MessageConsumed += this.Consumer_MessageConsumed;
            consumer.StartConsuming();
        }
    }
```

Comment: @HimBromBeere why do you post the answer as comment (I see many people doing this). Actually i like this answer, because it helps me with my problem, too. update: never mind, you posted it as answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try to simplify your code using [`Enum.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8) method:

```cs
 if (Enum.TryParse(setting.Name, true, out eventType)) 
     return eventType;
 else
     return ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified;
```

You can parse the `setting.Name` string to `ConsumedEventType`, use the parsed value, otherwise return `ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified` value.

It's easier than maintaining a list of values. In terms of your code above you can write something like that

```cs
foreach (var setting in consumerSettingsSection.QueueSettings)
{
    var eventType = ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified;
    if (Enum.TryParse(setting.Name, true, out ConsumedEventType parsedEvent))
    {
         eventType = parsedEvent;
    }
    //rest of code
}
```

Or even easier

```cs
if (!Enum.TryParse(setting.Name, true, out ConsumedEventType eventType))
{
    eventType = ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified;
}
```

Please, keep in mind that inline `out` variables are supported starting from C# 7

Comment: Thank you! this was really helpful!

Answer (score 4):

Use a `Dictionary<string, ConsumedEventType>`:

```
var d = new Dictionary<string, ConsumedEventType>() 
{
    { "A", ConsumedEventType.A },
    { "B", ConsumedEventType.B },
    { "C", ConsumedEventType.C },
    ...
}
```

Now get the actual value that fits your `settings.Name`:

```
ConsumedEventType type;
var type = !d.ContainsKey(settings.Name)
    ConsumedEventType.NotSpecified : 
    d[setting.sName];
```